# Global variable on android device

Tags: android, variables, global

Is there a setting like sharedpreference on whole android device(not app) that let apps to read and write some variable on device?(without any permission)
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing by default, but you can share data between apps by using a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html).

One of your apps should host a `ContentProvider` and you can query and modify it's data by other apps.

[Content Provider API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot.I will try it.